# ASP.NET MVC: Criteria for controller's method to be an action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm writing some unit tests to assert that all our controller action methods are marked with proper custom attributes, but I don't really know what the criteria is for determining whether a public method can act as MVC action or not.

I would assume that a criteria could be the return value type (it has to be `ActionResult` or a derivative). Is this true? What about static methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a method to be considered an action, it has to meet the following criteria:

- It must be `public` and not `static`
- It must not have a "special" name in order to exclude constructors, events etc.
- It must not be defined on `System.Web.Mvc.Controller` or any other base class in order to exclude `.ToString()` and family.

Generic methods will throw an exception, yet for some reason they `are` considered actions. As for the return type, it does not necessarily have to be an `ActionResult`, since you can return e.g. a `string` for text data.

Comment: The third point is what I was looking for: I didn't know what to do with methods like Dispose() and such. Thanks

Comment: Please note that it gets very tricky when you have things like the [NonAction] attribute applied to action methods. A public method that might otherwise appear to be an action method could have an attribute that overrides the default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I beleive all public methods in a controller are treated as actions - even one returning a string.

Comment: appart from the ones mentioned by saulius ;)

Answer (score 1):

Determining the true list of actions on a controller is a tricky problem. The only correct answer is that it "depends"! The list that Saulius gave is pretty much correct - if you're using the default ControllerActionInvoker - which of course, most people use.

If you want to avoid duplicating the logic I would recommend using the ControllerActionInvoker itself to get the list of actions and then verify the contents of the list that it returns.

You'll have to write a class that derives from ControllerActionInvoker so that you can call the GetControllerDescriptor() method. The return value of that method is a ControllerDescriptor, which is an abstract descriptor of what the controller has. You can then call GetCanonicalActions(), which returns a list of ActionDescriptors. Each of those items represents what is typically and action method.

To hook it all up you'll need to:

1. Instantiate your controller
2. Set its ActionInvoker property to be an instance of your custom invoker
3. Create a ControllerContext instance that has its Controller instance set to your controller
4. Call a new public method on your invoker that in turn calls GetControllerDescriptor()

Then verify the results and you're done!

Of course, I haven't tried any of this but in theory it all works :)